# explain high and low state

Tags: pullup, pulldown, push-pull

I have a TP4056 module (datasheet: https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf). It charges a 18650 cell.

According to the datasheet :

(Pin6): Open Drain Charge Status Output When the battery Charge Termination, the
pin is pulled low by an internal switch, otherwise STDBY pin is in high impedance state.

(Pin7): Open Drain Charge Status Output When the battery is being charged, the CHRG
pin is pulled low by an internal switch, otherwise CHRG pin is in high impedance state.

[image]

As expect, LED1 lights up when it is charging, because I can measure 0V at pin 7. And I can measure about 2.8V at pin 6, which is why LED2 does not light up. So far so good.

Since I do not need visual cues, I removed R1, R2, LED1, LED2. I soldered 2 wires at pin 6 and 7 because I want to read high/low states on a microcontroller and display the infos on an OLED screen instead.

[image]

This did not work as expected because now, while charging the battery cell, pin 6 reads about 0.5V (instead of about 2.8V before I desoldered what I deemed unnecessary components). So I cannot read the HIGH state on my microcontroller. Pin 7 still reds LOW, which is good. What did I do wrong? As far as I can understand from the datasheet, pin 6 should be internally pulled up at 5V, but I read 0.5V (or 2.8V before I altered it). What do I need to do to get rid of the LEDs and still be able to read the HIGH/LOW states of pin 6 and pin 7.

I tried the following without any success :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open drain means the pin will either be pulled low, or, it is not pulled or pushed into neither high or low state.

Just like a switch or button, that either connects to ground, or leaves disconnected.

So, pulling up the pins with 1k resistors should have worked, so the resistor then keeps the voltage at VIN+ when the chip does not pull low.

However it is unknown where your ground reference is connected to, but it should be the charger chip ground, as the output ground may be disconneced by the protection circuit FETs.

Also if VIN+ is larger voltage than what the MCU IO pins can withstand, it will do damage to the MCU, if the voltage and current are not sufficiently limited by suitably large resistors.

Comment: My two 1k pull-up resistors actually do the trick indeed. Not sure what I did wrong. Ill put 10k resistors instead, to limit power dissipation.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, those outputs are "Open Collector" or "Open Drain".  They have a transistor between the output pin and Ground, to pull the output Low, but nothing in the chip to pull the output High.

This arrangement is fine for driving LEDs, but if you remove the LEDs you need something else to pull the output High - typically a 10K or so resistor from the output pin to Vcc will do.